# Bootstrap 4 right to left custom file input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, right-to-left

i am trying to make the upload file input direction from bootstrap 4 right to left but nothing i tried so far worked

i also tried to change the direction for different tags

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" multiple lang="ar" dir="rtl">
                <label class="custom-file-label text-left" for="customFile">choose files to upload</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.custom-file input').change(function (e) {
                var files = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < $(this)[0].files.length; i++) {
                    files.push($(this)[0].files[i].name);
                }
                $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(files.join(', '));
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

[image: bootstrap upload file control style]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need a little custom CSS like this...

```
.custom-file-label::after {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right: inherit;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/kOURGBHqEX

Comment: Using the exact same code the grey "Browse" text cover the whole input (choose files is not visible).

Comment: @jul check the demo